# Unset ENV variables inside docker container through script which will be execute inside the same container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have passed env variables at the time of building docker image (in docker run command with --env flag) which is required at the build time only. How to remove these env variables after docker build is completed. I tried to unset those variables through a script which is being executed inside the docker container, but it did’t work for me.
Please help me out !!

Comment: Are the extra variables causing problems?  Is there a particular context you're seeing them, that you expect not to?  Can you edit the question to include your image's `Dockerfile`, the `docker run` command you're using, and the script to which you refer?

Comment: @DavidMaze These variables are not causing problem. Actually these are required at the build time only. So I dont want these extra variables in production.

`run docker container run -di $DEV \
    --name "$CTR_NAME" \
    --hostname $HOSTNAME --add-host localhost:$DOCKER0 \
    --env ENV_VARIABLE1=$VARIABLE1 \
    --env ENV_VARIABLE2=$VARIABLE2 \
    --tmpfs /tmp ...........`

I am exporting ENV_VARIABLE1 & ENV_VARIABLE2 inside docker container.
using them for some validations and operation inside container.I would like to remove them at the time or before the time of docker commit.

Comment: `docker run` isn't "build time", though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest avoiding the problem instead of trying to fix it.

1. If you need variables during build time, use [build args](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg).
2. If you want/need to use environment variables during build time, put them along with the commands that need them inside of a shell script and run it on build.
3. The `ENV` directive in `Dockerfile` is intended to set environment variables for the container. Don't abuse it so you wont have to fix the side effects.

If you insist on trying to fix it, and unsetting the variables on run time, you need to add the `unset` commands to the boot script of your image, for example:

```
FROM alpine
ENV SECRET there is no spoon
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN echo "unset SECRET" >> /root/.bashrc
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: Note that most common Docker paths won't read a `.bashrc` file or similar dotfiles.  This `ENTRYPOINT` will prevent things like `docker run ... ls -al /` from working (because `/bin/ls` isn't a shell script).  But an entrypoint script that `unset` variables and then `exec "$@"` to run the main container command will work.

Comment: I never said its a good idea to do this. My recommendation is to avoid the problem that brings the need to do this `unset` in the first place.